# Why such operations to a string would change a variable quantity?

Tags: string, segmentation-fault

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int t;
 cin>>t;
 while(t--)
 {
  int n;
  string s,ans;
  cin>>n>>s;
  bool check=false;
  int lenans=0;
  for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
   ans[lenans++]=s[i];
    if(s[i]=='a'||s[i]=='e')
   {
     check=true;
    }
   else{
    if(check&&i)
      {
       check=false;
      ans[lenans++]='.';
     }
    }
   }
  
  for(int i=lenans-1;i>=0;i--)
  cout<<ans[i];
  if(t)
 cout<<endl;
 }
}
```

That are codes for a problem:[text](https://codeforces.com/contest/1915/problem/D)

In the last test case(the length of string is 22),variable 'n' would be changed when variable 'i' is 4 in the circulation(row 16th).But in previous test cases,that wouldn't happen.However,if i turn the 18th code `ans[lenans++]=s[i];`  to  `ans.push_back(s[i])`,and also turn the 27th code to `ans.push_back('.');`  .That's fine.So why such operation would change n's value,even make segementation fault(if i initialize 'n' to long long class).(I am sorry for my poor English that might confuse you)

> Would you explain the reason that make such chaos?(n's value is changed)